# Multimedia Components are not updated when put into Workflow

Tags: workflow, 2011-sp1, multimedia

We're implementing Tridion Workflow onto some Multimedia Components and finding some issues where Workflow appears to ignore the updates.  This happened using a relatively complicated Workflow I was developing, but I was also able to reproduce it using a simple, manual Workflow:

### [image: Start -> Create or Edit Content (manual) -> Finish (manual) -> Stop]

If I open an existing Multimedia Component, say a Word document and follow the process:

1. Load from Disk (select the updated Word document)
2. Save and Close

Then the Component ends up in Workflow as expected.  However, if I open the Component from Workflow and either Save to disk or click the icon, I get the old version of the document.  The old version persists throughout the Workflow and the document is not updated when the Workflow ends.

I can work around this by doing the following opening the Component and adding a layer to the process, i.e.

1. Load from Disk (select the updated Word document)
2. Save and Close
3. Go to Workflow
4. Open the Component
5. Load from Disk (select the updated Word document)
6. Save and Close
7. Finish Activity ... (and complete Workflow)

However that seems a little cumbersome as it is making the same updated twice and I can't imagine it's by design unless I'm missing something obvious.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a bug?

This issue does not occur when used with non-multimedia Components.

Comment: Is this resolved with CM_2011.1.1.80080_Cumulative Hotfix https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CM_2011.1.1.80080_tcm89-20607.zip TT79280?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with Tridion SP1 HR1 (TT79280).  A hotfix is available [here](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx) as part of cumulative hotfix CM_2011.1.1.80080.